# Drupal: Restrict File Uploads by Permission

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

On my Drupal 7 site, I am looking for a way to only allow users with a specific role to upload PDF files. All users, however, will be able to upload other file types (e.g. jpg, mp4).

Is there a module or some code available that can accomplish that tool for me?

Answer (score 0):

You dont need a module for that.
You can write a hook_form_alter and do the following

```
 1. add help-text based on role.
if role = 1
#form['field_name']['#description'] = t('Help test 1')
elseif role = 2
#form['field_name']['#description'] = t('Help test 2')
```

2. Add custom validation to check file extension based on roles.

   $form['#validate'][] = 'validate_function';
   function validate_function
   if role = 1
   Validate file type 1
   elseif role = 2
   Validate file type 2

cheers!

Comment: could you elaborate your answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use `hook_form_alter` to achieve this.

load your user object

```
global $user;
$valid_role = 'yourGivenRole';

if(in_array($valid, $user->roles)){
     $form['field_name']['und'][0]['#upload_validators']['file_validate_extensions'][0]  = 'pdf';
}
```